# javacc parseException... lookahead problem?

Tags: parsing, grammar, interpreter, javacc, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a parser for a very simple grammar in javacc.  It's beginning to come together but at the moment I'm completely stuck on this error:

```
    ParseException: Encountered "" at line 4, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
```

The line of input in question is `z = y + z + 5`

and the production that is giving me problems is my expression which get called from
varDecl():

```
<ID> <EQL> expression()
```

Expression looks like this:

```
        <VAR> (<PLUS> expression())?| <NUM> (<PLUS> expression())? 
        | call() (<PLUS> expression())?
```

I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting this error - any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, yes, that's not a very helpful error from JavaCC.  What version of JavaCC are you using?

Also, it's difficult to troubleshoot these problems without seeing the full grammar... and although I understand you might not be in a position to post that.